# Wagtail Hide/Show menu item by user permissions

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

How to hide-show menu in wagtail CMS:
Here is my code on register_admin_menu_item hook inside `blog/wagtail_hooks.py`

```
    from wagtail.core import hooks
    from wagtail.admin.menu import MenuItem
    @hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item')
    def register_custom_admin_menu_item():
        return MenuItem(_('Site Admin'), reverse('admin_menu'), classnames='icon icon-folder-inverse',
         order=20000)
```

Answer (score 4):

For imposing the access on the menu, we can create the custom `MenuItem` Class and override the `is_shown` method as below:

```
        class CustomAdminMenuItem(MenuItem):
        def is_shown(self, request):
            return request.user.is_staff
```

Now use this `CustomAdminMenuItem`  instead of MenuItem like:

```
    from wagtail.core import hooks
    from wagtail.admin.menu import MenuItem
    @hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item')
    def register_custom_admin_menu_item():
        return CustomAdminMenuItem(_('Site Admin'), reverse('admin_menu'), classnames='icon icon-folder-inverse',
         order=20000)
```

You can implement custom permission check also using `has_perm` inside is_shown like:

```
    class CustomMenuItem(MenuItem):
        def is_shown(self, request):
            return (
                request.user.has_perm('wagtailsearchpromotions.add_searchpromotion') or
                request.user.has_perm('wagtailsearchpromotions.change_searchpromotion') or
                request.user.has_perm('wagtailsearchpromotions.delete_searchpromotion')
            )
```

For more details visit the source code [here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/db6d36845f3f2c5d7009a22421c2efab9968aa24/wagtail/admin/menu.py)  and doc [here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/dcab2c2163599e3dfe40d0a0e36b3d5e9290d39d/docs/reference/hooks.rst#register_admin_menu_item).